# How to make field unique only, instead of both indexed with unique in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am using `MongoDB` with `Spring Boot`. And I saw the below option:

```
@Indexed(unique=true)
```

which means that field is both indexed and unique, can we make it only unique.

I mean for my case unique is enough, I do not want to index that field, can we achieve that?

Comment: Mongodb uniqueness is enforced through unique index. So answer is no.

Comment: Mongodb need to create and index in order to know whether the field is unique, also apply for relational databases...